# How to make an object move in a circle - Java

Tags: java, radius

Id like to start by saying i'm very new at programming, so very simple, detailed, and easy-to-read code and answers are greatly appreciated!

I'm doing a Java Graphics Applet program that will move a simple sphere from Java's Draw method around the center of the program. ***The end goal is to have a method where i can specify the radius, size of sphere that will be moving, and speed it would move at, all in one method.***

For anyone who is awesome enough to help me out with my problem, a full program answer (from all the imports to the last "}") would be awesome, so i can copy/paste it and tinker with it to suit my program.

**If possible, id like to *not* use any 3rd party jars etc.**

Comment: You probably won't get far asking for full code without showing any kind of attempt at your assignment. You could also just try googling for a solution if you really don't want to try anything yourself.

Comment: (1-) If you want to tinker with something, then start with the [Swing Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/TOC.html). There is a section on `Custom Painting`. Read the tutorial download the code and change it to draw a circle. Then you can read the section on `How to Use Timers` to animate the motion of the circle in a straight line. Then then next step would be to do the circular motion. This is how you learn to code - one step at a time. We are not going to dump code for you. Show us you have made and effort and we will help with problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an example of the code you would need to fit those requirements.  This would show a small sphere that 'orbits' a point.  I'm solving the math for this, but you're on your own for implementing this using your graphics API (since I don't really have enough detail from your post).

Each time you call this method, you would increment the argument `timeInterval` by 1.  Note: This surely isn't the *best* way do this, but it fits your requirement of everything being in one method.

```
public void drawOrbitingSphere(int timeInterval) {

    // let's just choose a bunch of values that we'll need
    double orbitX = 100; /* x-coordinate in orbit's center */
    double orbitY = 100; /* y-coordinate in orbit's center */
    double orbitRadius = 50;
    double orbitSpeed = Math.PI / 16;
    double sphereRadius = 10;

    /*
     * based on the current time interval, we'll calculate where the sphere
     * is at on its orbit
     */
    double radian = orbitSpeed * timeInterval;
    double drawX = orbitX + orbitRadius * Math.cos(radian);
    double drawY = orbitY + orbitRadius * Math.sin(radian);

    // use whichever Draw method is provided by your API
    drawSphere(drawX, drawY, sphereRadius);
}
```